# How do we tag questions on maximizing/minimizing functions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I've noticed (when checking [newly created tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new)), that a tag called [max-min](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-min) has been created.

It has the following tag-excerpt:

> Questions related to maximizing or minimizing a expression or a function.

and the tag-wiki:

> Related to applications of derivatives
> max./min. of cost, a function expression etc.

(BTW it is nice that the creator of tag also created the tag-wiki. I think that people who create tags should do this, but not many of them do so.)

From my experience, such questions have been so far usually tagged as [optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization); this tag has the following tag-excerpt at this moment:

> Optimization is the process of choosing the "best" value among possible values. They are often formulated as questions on the minimization/maximization of functions, with or without constraints.

Based on the tag-excerpt this tag seems very suitable for this kind of questions. But the name [max-min](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-min) is also good, because if someone asks about maximizing or minimizing a function and looks for an appropriate tag, they will probably start typing something containing max or min.

---

I would like to ask the following

> - Are there some different tags apart from [optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) which should be used for questions about finding extrema of functions?
> - Should [max-min](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-min) and [optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) by synonymized?
> - Are there other names who should be useful as synonyms for [max-min](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-min) or for [optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization); which would help the users in choice of correct tags? (E.g. the user might be tempted to look for [extrema](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extrema) tag, when he asks question like this.)

Comment: For the curious, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62290) is how the tag came to be. *shrugs*

Comment: With extreme care? :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[max-min](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-min) would be a nice synonym for [optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization), I think, so I propose a merger, with the proper term [optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) still as the tag of choice, and [max-min](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-min) and [extrema](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extrema) as synonyms. Maybe put in [minimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minimization) and [maximization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maximization) while we're at it...

Comment: I wish the lone dissenter has a damn better idea than I do...

Comment: done. synonyms created.